# get last record from list in freemarker

Tags: java, spring-mvc, freemarker

```
    <select name="showYears">
            <#list payrollYears as year> 
                <option value="${year.year}">${year.yeardesc}</option>
            </#list>        
    </select>
```

i am getting payrollyears list from my controller and i am iterating the list in freemarker and adding value to select box i want my last value of list should be selected value in last how can i do that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do something like

```
<#list payrollYears as year> 
      <option value="${year.year}" <#if !(year_has_next)>selected</#if> >${year.yeardesc}</option>
</#list>
```

Answer (score 7):

For FreeMarker 2.3.24, you can do something like `year?has_next` instead of `year_has_next`.

- `item_has_next` (deprecated by `item?has_next`): Boolean value that tells if the current item is the last in the sequence or not.

See [FreeMarker Docs](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
<#list body.result as school_names_list>
{
  "NAME": <#if school_names_list.NAME??>"${school_names_list.NAME}"<#else>""</#if>,
  "ADDRESS": <#if school_names_list.ADDRESS??>"${school_names_list.ADDRESS}"<#else>""</#if>,
   <#if school_names_list?is_last><#else>,</#if>
</#list>


//Here **school_names_list** is a list and we check the last element though **school_names_list?is_last** (where list name is school_names_list)

//In this example, if it the last element, ***we'll avoid adding "," else we add "," as per JSON rules of a list.***
```

Comment: In this example we are making a list which is JSON.Hence, as in a json list, all the elements are separated by "," except the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but you can use `is_last`.

Using your code you could write your code like this;

```
<select name="showYears">
  <#list payrollYears as year>
    <#if year?is_last>
      <option value="${year.year}" selected>${year.yeardesc}</option>
    <#else>
      <option value="${year.year}">${year.yeardesc}</option>
    </#if>
  </#list>        
</select>
```

---

A better way would be to add the `selected` straight to the HTML, and drop the whole `if` check around it, but **not entierly sure** how to add this directly to **HTML as valid syntax**.

So this probably WON'T work, but my line of thinking is something like this;

```
<select name="showYears">
  <#list payrollYears as year>
    <option value="${year.year}" ${year?is_last?then('selected', '')}>${year.yeardesc}</option>
  </#list>        
</select>
```